# Rendering script tag contents in PHP module, Drupal

Tags: javascript, php, drupal

Hello: I think what I am trying to achieve is simple, but I'm stuck. I've tried a few different combinations but have yet to find the solution.

I have a page and it contains HTML and an embedded script tag with some JavaScript

In Drupal, I am trying to load the HTML, as is, and return it back. My PHP looks like:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $html = $doc->saveHTML();

    $element = array(
    '#markup' => $html
    );
```

All of my HTML tags like anchors, etc. are fine. How can I get the scripts to be rendered as scripts and not text?

I've tried using file and file_get_contents as well with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `$doc->saveHTML(TRUE);` ?